# Invalid property "style" for Button

Tags: qt, qml

Why am I getting this error: `invalid property "style"` every time I use the `style` property?

```json
Button {
    text: "A button"
    style: ButtonStyle {
        background: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 25
            border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
            border.color: "#888"
            radius: 4
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: control.pressed ? "#ccc" : "#eee" }
                GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: control.pressed ? "#aaa" : "#ccc" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use four spaces to format as code. And then when updating your question, please also include where you defined `Button` and `ButtonStyle`, as it stands QtQuick.Controls doesn't have a `style` property, so that's why you get the error

Comment: so how can i style a button ? i want a rectangle button with a specific color

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `QtQuick.Controls.Button`, you can use the following:

```
Button {
   id: control
   text: "A button"

   background: Rectangle {
       implicitWidth: 100
       implicitHeight: 25
       border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
       border.color: "#888"
       radius: 4
       gradient: Gradient {
           GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: control.pressed ? "#ccc" : "#eee" }
           GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: control.pressed ? "#aaa" : "#ccc" }
       }
   }
}
```

If you are using this definition repeatedly, you can put it (with `text: "A button"`) in a separate file, which you can call `MyButton.qml`, then you can use `MyButton { text: "A Button" }`

Comment: i am a beginner in qml so have not much idea about it.  How can i change the color of a button. the above code is not working the color is still gray

Comment: Please share your whole code or a minimal complete example, because this is not working. We cannot help when not showing all the parts involved

Comment: btw, maybe it's because you are actually using gray colors :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rectangle, Text and MouseArea Components to create button. By this way, there is no need style. You can do it like,

```
Rectangle{
    implicitWidth: 100
    implicitHeight: 25
    border.width: control.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
    border.color: "#888"
    radius: 4
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: control.pressed ? "#ccc" : "#eee" }
        GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: control.pressed ? "#aaa" : "#ccc" }
    }
    Text{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("A button")
    }
    MouseArea{
        id: control
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            //Your Button Function
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gray is the default color of a button in qml. If you would like to style it this is an option I use frequently. Create a rectangle child component of button, set anchors.fill, and then set a color on the rectangle. This will be the color of your button now.